# Getting PNG images from clipboard in C++

Tags: c++, windows, png, clipboard, file-format

I'm trying to get images from my clipboard that are all in PNG format. Every program is storing these images differently though. The Windows screenshot tool is copying just how I need it. Which is directly in the PNG format in the clipboard. ShareX copies with a C# class name and some other bytes before the PNG header. Firefox "Copy Image" seems to be copying the raw pixels. And Windows copy file is copying the file name. I am using http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/inside_clipboard.html to view this clipboard data. Is there a universal way to grab what I'm looking for? Programs like Firefox, GIMP, and pretty much anywhere else you can paste images into don't seem to have any issues with this.

I only need this to work on Windows.